# Computing marginal posterior in a multivariate setting

Tags: bayesian, econometrics, posterior, marginal-distribution

I am computing posteriors using individual level data and would like to know if my formulation in the end is right.

Let the sequence of choices made by individual $i$ be $y = y_1, y_2 ......y_j$ in the data.
Our parameters are $\theta, \omega, \tau$
We are modeling $\theta, \omega$ as distributions and $\tau$ as a constant.
Given this model, probability of observing the choices made by individual $i$ is:

let
$ \beta = \begin{bmatrix}
\theta\\
\omega\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$
P(y|\beta,\tau) = P(y_1|\beta,\tau) .... P(y_n|\beta,\tau) 
$

Since $\beta$ is a distribution with parameters $\eta =\{\mu_\theta,\sigma_\theta,\mu_\omega, \sigma_\omega \}$ to obtain the above probability we evaluate the following integral

$
P(y|\eta) = \int P(y|\beta) g(\beta|\eta) d\beta
$

$g(\beta|\eta)$ is the joint distribution of $ \beta = \begin{bmatrix}
\theta\\
\omega\\
\end{bmatrix}$ given parameters $\eta$

The density $g(\beta|\eta)$ describes distribution of $\beta$ in the population. We can infer the information about each individuals's $\beta$ by conditioning on the individual's observed sequence of choices. Let $h(\beta| y,\eta)$ be the density of $\beta$ conditional on the sequence of choices of an individual $i$.

Then,

$
h(\beta|y,\eta) = \frac{P(y|\beta) . g(\beta|\eta)}{P(y|\eta)}
$

We use the above to compute conditional expectation of $\beta$ and its functions like $k(\beta) = \beta^2$.

if $k(\beta)$ is a function of $\beta$, then

$
E(k|y,\eta) = \frac{\int k(\beta) . P(y|\beta) . g(\beta|\eta) d\beta}{P(y|\beta) . g(\beta|\eta)d\beta}
$

We approximate this as

$
\hat{E}(k|y,\eta) = \frac{\sum_{r=1}^n k(\beta^r) . P(y|\beta^r)}{\sum_{r=1}^n P(y|\beta^r)} 
$

Where n is the number of random draws. $\beta^r$ is the $r^{th}$ random draw from the joint normal distribution of $\beta$ with parameters $\eta$ that are estimated using maximum likelihood.

To get expectations of $\theta_i, \omega_i$ for an individual $i$

$
\hat{E}(\beta_i|y,\eta) = \frac{\sum_{r=1}^n \beta^r . P(y|\beta^r)}{\sum_{r=1}^n P(y|\beta^r)} 
$

Where $ \beta^r = \begin{bmatrix}
\theta^r\\
\omega^r\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Since $P(y|\beta^r)$ and ${\sum_{r=1}^n P(y|\beta^r)}$ are just scalars we can write expectations of $\theta_i, \omega_i$ as follows:

$
\hat{E}(\theta_i|y,\eta) = \frac{\sum_{r=1}^n \theta^r . \frac{\sum_{s = 1}^n P(y|(\theta^r,\omega^s))}{n}}{\sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{\sum_{s = 1}^n P(y|(\theta^r,\omega^s))}{n}} 
$

$
\hat{E}(\omega_i|y,\eta) = \frac{\sum_{r=1}^n \omega^r . \frac{\sum_{s = 1}^n P(y|(\theta^s,\omega^r))}{n}}{\sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{\sum_{s = 1}^n P(y|(\theta^s,\omega^r))}{n}} 
$

Are these last two equations correct? Do I need to take the double summation here?

Comment: Are the choices independent from each other as you seem to suggest? Do all individuals have the same $\beta$ or have you dropped the index $i$ here?